# How do I stop Compiz from crashing when I change some configuration?

Tags: 11.10, unity, compiz, installation

My story is this:

I have a laptop toshiba satellite A665-SP6004, Intel Core i7 inside, Nvidia GeForce GT 330M graphics.

I recently switch to ubuntu 11.10 and I have experienced some problems, one of them is Compiz:

- Suddenly, compiz is turned off and since unity is a compiz plugin, this makes it drop out of the interface. This also happens every time I make a modification of anything, for example configure the AWN, which is very annoying.

Another problem I had is:

- to turn off the pc is locked. After clicking on shut down, the top panel turns purple and the rest of the black screen freezes, then I have to force it off, which is very risky.
- The keypad light. Works perfectly in Windows but still does not work in ubuntu ...

If someone can tell me how to solve at least the problem I have with compiz that will be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We are most able to help you if you write your posts in English. Could you please translate your question so we can understand what you're asking? Thanks!

Comment: At any rate, from my extremely limited knowledge of Spanish, it sounds like you're asking a number of different things. If you could please repost each question as a separate one, that'd be great.

Comment: Por favor, pedimos solamente una pregunta a la vez. Le sugiero que les pregunte de nuevo por separado. Si puede, pregúntele en Inglés - esto le ayudará mucho. ¡Gracias! -- Please ask only one question at a time. I suggest you ask them again separately. If you can, ask them in English - this will help a great deal. Thank you!

Comment: Vote to reopen: He is really asking only about his compiz problem, the turn off problem is likely related. We can try to answer it here. I agree that he should open another question for the keypad light.

Comment: I agree with Javier. How to reopen? This nice guy needs help and we could as well edit his question to make it be more obviously appear as a question?

Comment: You guys make good points, I'm happy to oblige. If you could edit the question accordingly, that'd be great.

Comment: Is this question still active ? It was re-opened, but no answers to the problem. Is it better filed as a bug report ?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 1):

On your desktop, make a file (it doesn't matter what it's called). Open it, and type this:

compiz --replace

close and save it.  Make it executable.  While you are changing the settings, make sure it's visible.  When compiz crashis, double click it and run it, and compiz should restart itself (not the computer).
This won't stop it from crashing, but now you won't have to restart your computer.